# CSS or JS solution to forcing a page to have no downward scroll and remain 100% window height

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://testing.gamemode.org/

I'm trying to ensure that the page shows only the height of the window, even if resized, and does not scroll down, ever. I want no scroll bar. My current attempted method is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper
{
height:100%;
overflow:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<iframe src="https://media.embed.ly/1/frame?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitch.tv%2Fgamemode_mc_&amp;width=1280&amp;secure=true&amp;key=0202f0ddb5a3458aabf520e5ab790ab9&amp;height=800" width="1280" height="800" border="0"     scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to achieve what I'm trying to get?

Edit: In fact, I'd like to force the iframe to resize to fit the page, stretching if necessary.

Comment: It's not acceptable to link to live code on this site. Your question needs to contain everything required to answer the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5pz6f/

Comment: @meagar I linked the live site to give a graphic example of what I'm wanting to do, but I provide 100% of the code used in the question.

Comment: @jt0dd Still not acceptable. Even if you tell us you plan to leave that code there, at that address, unchanged, forever, we still won't trust that you'll actually do it.

Comment: @meagar I understand. I'm still, after using this site many times, getting used to the many very particular rules and policies

Comment: It's not that peculiar if you accept that Stack Overflow is meant to be a work of reference. Your question is going to be around for a long time, and it's meant to help anybody who has a similar problem in the future. By including a link to external code, you've made your question brittle: As soon as you fix the problem in the external code so that it no longer reflects the problem your question is about, the link is useless. Nevermind what happens if you just take the page down, or the link otherwise breaks.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you, I'll be careful to follow this concept in all future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the CSS rules to the body and the `iframe` as well

```
body, .wrapper, iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:none;
}
```

Comment: It seems like that should work just fine, but that, for some reason, seems to make the page the right height while mysteriously cutting the iframe off unusually.

Comment: Is the text outside of the iframe? If so you'd have to change it a bit

Comment: @jt0dd Did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: This question wasn't answered at first, I'd forgotten, thanks for reminding me. *reading*

Answer (score 1):

If you give your wrapper a `position: absolute` this should work in most modern browsers.